# Li-ion battery load sharing

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-operated, tp4056, sim800

I'm designing a backup battery for some portable sim800 project.

In [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01149c.pdf) application note, page 5 it counts problems of connecting load to battery directly.

but for example in [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/17660) schematic of Adafruit Fona, they connected battery to SIM module. I think because Using MOSFET between battery & GPRS module(sim800c in my case) is inefficient and may cause some problems.

Is this important to have power sharing like figure below, for sim800 (with low power consumption)?[image]

Comment: Assuming that you are using some li-ion charging IC like on the Figure 5 the circuit marked red will just supply power to the load from the IC input (eg USB) not from battery. It will not affect the current consumption while running from the battery

Comment: _"Using MOSFET between battery & GPRS module(sim800c in my case) is inefficient and may cause some problems."_ - what is the expected on time, duty cycle, and current draw relative to the charging current?

Comment: @bruce the average current draw is 10mA, but it has some very short ~2A spikes. The charging current is 1A (using tp4056 module).